# OpenLDAP AccessLogs out of hand

Tags: openldap

I've got over 150 GB of logs in /var/lib/ldap/accesslog and for some reason they won't rotate out or purge old logs.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I'm using HDB.

I'm using an OLC setup, so I have no slapd.conf file.

My Slapd version is 2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8.2

My AccessLog overlay is configured with:

```
dn: olcOverlay={1}accesslog
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAccessLogConfig
olcOverlay: {1}accesslog
olcAccessLogDB: cn=accesslog
olcAccessLogOps: writes
olcAccessLogPurge: 7+00:00 1+00:00
olcAccessLogSuccess: TRUE
...
```

Unfortunately I still have log files dated from November of 2014, which is probably when this server was upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the LDAP services were re-initialized from a backup LDIF file.

I've tried creating a DB_CONFIG file in the accesslog directory containing the following:

```
set_flags DB_LOG_AUTOREMOVE
```

to no avail.

Comment: If you change anything about the database configuration you need to rerun `slapindex` to have it take effect.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the "set_flags DB_LOG_AUTOREMOVE" didn't kick in until I restarted the slapd service.  As soon as I did the old logs were purged out.